# Copying MySQL database from test server to local MAMP server

Tags: mysql, command-line, mamp

I may have gone completely braindead today, but I'm having trouble copying my DB down to my local MAMP server. I'm not too familiar with mysqldump, etc, but I want to know how to copy a database from a test server to my MAMP local server in the easiest way possible. I have very limited experience with server stuff, but have a bit of experience with command line.

Any straight-forward help would be much appreciated. I look forward to smacking myself in the head when I realise what a dick I've been ;)

Dalogi

Comment: Can you connect to either MySQL server remotely? Typically this is disabled, but since they are your machines, if they are on, that would be easiest.

Comment: Yes, I can access both, but having mental block as to how to copy across :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mysqldump's the best way:

```
on the test server: mysqldump -p name_of_db > dump.sql
on the map server: mysql -p < dump.sql
```

The dump file contains the full instructions in SQL query format to recreating the db, it stable structure, and data. The -p option forces both apps to prompt for your password. If your MySQL username is different than your system's login account, then you'll need the -u option as well:

```
mysqldump -p -u yourDBusername name_of_db > dump.sql
mysql -p -u yourDBusername < dump.sql
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work. I may be being stupid (yet again) but the second command isn't working. So here's my n00b question: I have my dump file on the test server, and now I want to copy it over to my desktop or localhost. Any ideas?

Comment: ssh, ftp, stick the file into your webroot and use wget/curl, sneakernet, etc... there's many ways to transfer a file between two machines.

Comment: that's what I need to know? FTP doesn't work. Tried the following, but that doesn't work – scp server:dump.sql /path/to/folder/ – and that doesn't work, as it's saying permission denied! I can't believe I'm having so many problems just copying a file from A to B.

Comment: scp's syntax is "scp source destination". if you're doing this from the mamp server's shell, then you'd want `scp username@the_devel_box_name:/path/to/original/file  /path/to/where/on/mamp/you/want/it`

Comment: – I love you!! ;) Problem solved. After a restart and using your scp syntax it worked a treat. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

```
mysqldump -h 'remotehost' -uremoteuser -premotepass db_name | mysql -ulocaluser -plocalpass db_name
```